# Is it possible to inject a method into a service in symfony services.yml

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

There is already plenty of documentation on the internet about injecting a service into another service like this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html

However, I already have a service called `ObjectCache` which is configured in symfony's services.yml like this:

```
object_cache:
  class: App\Bundle\ApiBundle\Service\ObjectCache
```

This service currently has two methods for getting and setting a User object. For example:

```
$user = new User(); // assume entity from database
$this->get('object_cache')->setUser($user);
// ...
$this->get('object_cache')->getUser(); // instance of $user
```

I want to create a new service which always depends on a user, so makes sense to inject the user at service creation:

```
class SomeService {
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
    }
}
```

How would I configure services.yml such that the User is injected into my new service?

```
object_cache:
  class: App\Bundle\ApiBundle\Service\ObjectCache
some_service:
  class: App\Bundle\ApiBundle\Service\SomeService
  arguments: [@object_cache->getUser()????]
```

This didn't work, and symfony yaml documentation is sketchy to say the least.

Am I basically forced into creating a User-only flavour of the ObjectCache and injecting that into SomeService OR expecting SomeService to receive an ObjectCache and call getUser once in the constructor?

Comment: A service factory is what you are looking for: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html You will end up with an injectable object_cache_user service.

Comment: You can use the expression language like `"@service('object_cache').getUser"` (see http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/book/service_container.html#using-the-expression-language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to [qooplmao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1791606/qooplmao) for their comment in helping me find the answer as [this is exactly what I was looking for](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/book/service_container.html#using-the-expression-language). I thought I'd answer my own question for the benefit of others as **I now have this working**, plus some corrections to the syntax in the comment.

What I should have been looking for was Symfony's **Expression Language** which allows precisely the granularity of control I was looking for.

The resulting configuration now looks like this:

```
object_cache:
  class: App\Bundle\ApiBundle\Service\ObjectCache
some_service:
  class: App\Bundle\ApiBundle\Service\SomeService
  arguments: [@=service('object_cache').getUser()]
```

For more information on the Expression Syntax, here is some detailed documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/components/expression_language/syntax.html

(If only Symfony docs had the courtesy to provide links to such crucial information on pages that make reference to it!)